# Каким образом можно сделать отправку определённого сообщения при невыполнения функции в Питон для тг-бота?(либа телебот)

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Есть функция, благодаря которой бот изменяет ссылку, парсит от туда файл и конвертирует его в jpg
В боте создано 3 кнопки, т.е. для расписания "Вчера", "Сегодня" и "Завтра"
Но, например, в воскресенье нет расписания на сайте и бот в тг ничего не выводит, а в терминале - ошибку
Нужно, чтоб в случае, если функция не выполнилась, т.е. изменённая ссылка не была найдена и последующие действия не были сделаны, выводилось сообщение по типу "Ничего не найдено"
Вот часть кода:

```
    elif message.text == "Завтра":
        date = str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(1), '%d.%m.%Y'))
        link = f"https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/Расписание%20{date}.pdf"
#Сохранение файла
        response = requests.get(link)
        pdf = open("pdf.pdf", 'wb')
        pdf.write(response.content)
        pdf.close()
#Конверт в пнг
        file_path = "pdf.pdf"
        dpi = 300 #Параметры, которые всегда одинаковые
        zoom = dpi / 72 #Зум, который тоже можно не трогать
        magnify = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom) #Применение зума
        page = fitz.open(file_path) #Открытие файла
        pix = page[0].get_pixmap(matrix=magnify) #Конвертер в пнг
        pix.save("page.png") #Сохранение фото
        img = open("page.png", 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=img)
#Отправка при несуществующем расписании
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать else?
Например отдельная функция if среда:...
elif пятница :... else:...